# How to split multiple rows in to single row but multiple columns in AWS athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-athena

I have a dataset like below:
[image]

Now, I want to convert `role_clai` where I am getting multiple records per claim into two or more columns like `role_clai1` and `role_clai2` in case I get 3 records for the same ID.  I tried the below query:

```
SELECT client,active,claim,role_polh,role_agnt,
  kv1['CLAI'] AS A_v1,
  kv1['CLAI'] as clai2
FROM (
  SELECT client,active,claim,role_polh,role_agnt,map_agg(claim,role_clai) kv1
  FROM "final_view"
  GROUP BY client,active,claim,role_polh,role_agnt
)  where claim = '00600000000015609'
```

`Output:`

[image]

`Expected output:`

The two values for role_clai should be divided among the two newly created columns.

As it can be seen that for the two columns created I am not getting any values. So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try to work with [`array_agg`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html) rather than `map_agg` as the key will be similar for the whole map:

> **array_agg(x) → array<[same as input]>**
> Returns an array created from the input x elements.

You should be then able to access array elements with `role_claims[1]` or `element_at`:

```sql
SELECT client,active,claim,role_polh,role_agnt,
element_at(role_claims,1) AS role_clams_1,
element_at(role_claims,2) AS role_claims_2
FROM (
  SELECT client,active,claim,role_polh,role_agnt,array_agg(role_clai) role_claims
  FROM "final_view"
  GROUP BY client,active,claim,role_polh,role_agnt
)  where claim = '00600000000015609'
```

Comment: Your query doesn't work when I have a single record. As per expectation, the second column should generate a blank value. I have posted an answer in the comments. Please edit your answer.

Comment: `select client,claim,active,role_agnt,role_polh, element_at(clai, 1) AS role_clai1,
 element_at(clai, 2) AS reole_clai2,element_at(clai, 3) AS role_clai3 from 
(SELECT client,claim,active,role_agnt,role_polh,array_agg(role_clai) as clai from "sapabap1"."final_view"
group by  client,claim,active,role_agnt,role_polh)c` I have used `element_at` for the outer query